Chroma db reset enabling issue
I am just trying to reset a database hosted on a docker container:
import chromadb
from chromadb.config import Settings

client = chromadb.HttpClient(host="localhost", port=8000, settings=Settings(allow_reset=True))
client.reset()

But, the above code throws the following exception:
Exception: {"error":"ValueError('Resetting is not allowed by this configuration (to enable it, set `allow_reset` to `True` in your Settings() or include `ALLOW_RESET=TRUE` in your environment variables)')"}

I am not sure why it is causing this issue, any help would be appreciated!

I had exactly the same issue with my implementation:
chroma_client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=CHROMADB_PATH)

and came here looking for a fix—but when I added the same setting as you:
chroma_client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=CHROMADB_PATH, settings=Settings(allow_reset=True))

it just worked! Is there any chance you're running a previous version of your code? Or caching something? Is the URI the local one?

Well I am using httpclient... can you still access the http hosted db with persistent Client?

Please don’t post answers saying that a problem is unreproducible to you. Those are better suited for comments.

Issue resolved when I added
-e ALLOW_RESET=TRUE

on my docker run command
